# Python: Best practice for dynamically constructing regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a simple function to remove a "word" from some text:

```
def remove_word_from(word, text):
    if not text or not word: return text
    rec = re.compile(r'(^|\s)(' + word + ')($|\s)', re.IGNORECASE)    
    return rec.sub(r'\1\3', text, 1)
```

The problem, of course, is that if word contains characters such as "(" or ")" things break, and it generally seems unsafe to stick a random word in the middle of a regex.

What's best practice for handling cases like this? Is there a convenient, secure function I can call to escape "word" so it's safe to use?

Comment: Note that `r"\n" + "\n"` is not the same as `r"\n" + r"\n"`, though Python lets you slide with \s here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `re.escape(word)` to escape the word.

Comment: This is a great suggestion -- superior to mine as long as you do not intend for word to have anything like \n and \t in it.

Comment: I would also ask him to use `\b` word boundary character.

Comment: @Ishpeck: Even in that case, this is superior.  If you want to parse escape sequences in word, then do that before re.escape.  And, of course, if you have those escapes directly in the source (word = "ab\nc"), then word has a literal newline rather than "\n".

Comment: This is why Stackoverflow is awesome. Somehow I'd missed both re.escape and \b, will be using both.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're forced to use regexps, couldn't you use instead the `replace` method for strings ?

```
text = text.replace(word, '')
```

This allows you to get rid of punctuation issues.

Comment: Though it's often good to consider whether you need regex, using \b (or the not-quite-identical alternative in the question) and re.IGNORECASE makes the regex much easier than correctly doing it otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Write a sanitizer function and pass word through that first.

```
def sanitize(word):
    def literalize(wd, escapee):
        return wd.replace(escapee, "\\%s"%escapee)
    return reduce(literalize, "()[]*?{}.+|", word)

def remove_word_from(word, text):
    if not text or not word: return text
    rec = re.compile(r'(^|\s)(' + sanitize(word) + ')($|\s)', re.IGNORECASE)    
    return rec.sub(r'\1\3', text, 1)
```

Comment: This is not enough. You also need to escape [], *, ?, etc.

Comment: Don't write a sanitizer function; use re.escape.

Comment: Good catch, Vlad H.  Changed it to reflect that.

Comment: The problem I have with re.escape() is what if you want word to contain literal tabs?

Comment: @Ishpeck: Then put literal tabs in it: word = "\t".

Comment: Writing your own sanitizer function is the surest way to do it wrong.  For example, the one here forgets to escape backslash.